# Why does my left shift function give a seg fault unless I use an if statement to terminate?

Tags: c

I'm using a piece of code to shift all the characters in my string by one place to the left. Here's the code:

```
char* leftshift(unsigned char *fmla){
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i != strlen(fmla); i++) {
         /* if (i == strlen(fmla)-1){
         fmla[i] = 0;
         return fmla;
         } */
         *(fmla + i) = *(fmla + i + 1);
     }
     return fmla;
}
```

If I run this code, it will give a seg fault. If I uncomment the commented code block, then it will run correctly. Why is this? The last character is null character (0) anyway, so the if statement shouldn't be doing anything that the loop wouldn't otherwise do. I don't understand why it works with the if statement and gives a seg fault without it.

Comment: Compile all your application with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to find out how, where, and why it is crashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you recalculate the `strlen` every time in the loop, and using `!=` instead of `<`. The bug occurs at the very last step of your perception, but in fact when you copy `NULL` from last element of the array, the `strlen` then return less value than before so the loop continues afterward. This code should fix it.

```
char* leftshift(unsigned char *fmla){
    int i;
    int len = strlen(fmla);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        *(fmla + i) = *(fmla + i + 1);
    }
    return fmla;
}
```

Example for string of length 4:

> ```
> i     strlen at the for
> 0     4
> 1     4
> 2     4
> 3     4      << The final element
> 4     3      << Unfortunately, the length has decreased in last iteration...
> ```

Comment: Ah okay, I forgot that strings were mutable in C and the string length could change. Thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 1):

You access the string at index `i+1`, and the loop terminates when i == strlen(fmla), which is too late because in last iteration you access one char after the string.

Answer (score 0):

Like 'Alter Mann' and 'dkrikun' say, you are accessing an out-of-bounds element. Consider the following to fix it:

```
char* leftshift(unsigned char *fmla){
int i;
for (i = 1; i != strlen(fmla); i++) {
  /* if (i == strlen(fmla)-1){
    fmla[i] = 0;
    return fmla;
   } */
    *(fmla + i - 1) = *(fmla + i);
}
return fmla;
}
```

Note that `i` is initialised to 1 and the pointer arithmetic has been updated (I've made minimal changes to highlight the error, but you should listen to the advice about calculating `strlen(fmla)` only once).

I assume the reason this error is hiding when your code is uncommented is explained by the following, from http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/498711-segmentation-fault-if-i-dont-use-printf:

> it is likely you have a wayward pointer or are going past your
>   array bounds. The printf masks it (because your program's code and data
>   layout is changed by the presence of that line), but the problem is
>   still there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If strln(fmla) == 0 it will crash to.